# add a numerical prefix to an index in a df and reset it when a different name appears

Tags: pandas

I hve the following df:

```
      xx
 A     5
 A     7
 A     4
 B     4 
 B     7
 B     6
```

How could I add an ascending numerical prefix such like this:

```
        xx
 1_A     5
 2_A     7
 3_A     4
 1_B     4 
 2_B     7
 3_B     6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create counter Series by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and `level=0` per index, add `1` with convert to strings and add to index values:

```
df.index = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str) + '_' + df.index
```

Or use [`Series.str.cat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html):

```
df.index = df.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str).str.cat(df.index, sep='_')
```

---

```
print (df)
     xx
1_A   5
2_A   7
3_A   4
1_B   4
2_B   7
3_B   6
```